# What is the recommended way to make multiple instances of Worker role do the same job?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

My worker role expose a **WCF service** and have multiple instances.

I want my client to call this service and make **all instances** working **concurrently**.

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to do this **scatter-gather** task.

(And I'm trying to avoid service bus and use WCF only)

Comment: Are you calling your service asynchronously from the client?  What version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any good way to do this without something like service bus topics.  Or using custom functionality that does nearly the same thing.  Why are you trying to avoid Service Bus?

Answer (score 0):

There's really no way to make a client-side call to multiple server instances simultaneously, just using Azure's built-in services. Even using Service Bus topics, there's no way to guarantee that multiple subscribers will consume a message at the same time and execute at the same time (even with a message embargo time, you still cannot absolutely guarantee each subscriber will consume + process a message at an exact time).

This will need to be an application-side action. For example: You can queue up your wcf requests. Your queue-reader can then direct-connect to an internal endpoint on each instance, triggering an action to run in parallel. This won't give you *exact* parallel operation, but it will be *pretty close*. As another option, you can have several threads available per instance, and you could run the same request on each thread (again, managed by you).

In essence, this is an architectural facet of your app. Azure won't be able to facilitate a parallel-call across instances; you can take advantage of queues, internal services, etc. to accomplish this.